# Update url for my appliction transfer the user to the app page but without the update option

Tags: android, google-play

i'm suggesting the user to update my app, and transfer him to the specific page on the play store. it work well for users that download the app from the store and really suggest them to update.

But the problem when the user download the app from other place, in this case he will enter the right page in the play store but without "update" option - only "open" and "uninstall" 
what can I do in this case?

Thank you all! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it happens because signature of your APK file is different in Google Play and in other place. Google Play allows to update an app only if signature has not been changed.

Signature difference could happen because:

- Amazon AppStore changes signature of your APK file
- Debug version of your app is always signed with debug singature

Read more about signing Android apps here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html